# Unable to read table row using MSHTML object

Tags: c#, html, microsoft.mshtml

I am developing a Windows application using C# in which I have used an MSHTML object to read the table rows from the DOM (HTML). The table has `THead` and `TBody` tags and inside them a `<TR>` tag.

When the HTML page is opened inside IE 9, then all table rows are rendered. When the HTML is opened in IE 11, then it renders only rows inside the `THead` tag.

What could be the reason for the different behavior in the different browser version?

I am loading the DOM from IE to get all values. A sample HTML:

```
<TABLE>
    <THEAD>
        <TR>
           <TD></TD>
        </TR>
     <THEAD>
     <TBODY>
        <TR>
           <TD></TD>
        </TR>
     <TBODY>
</TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe too late, but the THEAD is never closed and inside the THEAD they always use TH-Tags instead of TD, maybe this solves the problem

i think it should look like this:

```
<TABLE>
    <THEAD>
        <TR>
           <TH></TH>
        </TR>
     </THEAD>
     <TBODY>
        <TR>
           <TD></TD>
        </TR>
     <TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp